# Accesing more Window Extra Bytes than LongPointer

Tags: winapi

Im trying to figure out of how to correctly work with the Extra Bytes that you can let windows allocate for your windows and window classes.

If i'm reading the docs correctly, you can tell windows to allocate a specified amount of memory for your window or window class.
But there is only two methods i could find to access and modify said data, SetWindowLongPtr and GetWindowLongPtr.

Problem is, with those methods you can only set a LongPtr full of data, so 64 / 32 bits depending on your system.

Can somebody explain this to me, is there a method i am missing or is this as it should be?

Comment: In `WNDCLASS` you can tell it how many extra bytes you want. `SetWindowLongPtr` sets a pointer-sized value at the offset you specify. If you want two pointers, set `cbExtraBytes` to `2 * sizeof(LONG_PTR)` and then use offsets `0 * sizeof(LONG_PTR)` and `1 * sizeof(LONG_PTR)` to access them.

Comment: simply allocate your own memory (class object) and save pointer to it inside `GWLP_USERDATA`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Is it a problem that you cannot store data that's smaller than a pointer value in size, or do you need to store more data than a single pointer-sized value can hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Get|Set)WindowLong()` accesses a value at the specified `nIndex` as a whole `LONG`.

`(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr()` accesses a value at the specified `nIndex` as a whole `LONG_PTR`.

So yes, this does mean that `(Get|Set)WindowLongPtr()` will access a different number of bytes depending on whether you are compiling your project for 32bit or 64bit.  As such, if you want to read/write a smaller number of bytes, you will have to read/write a whole `LONG/_PTR` and do some bit shifting as needed.

Even though you can specify an arbitrary byte count for the `WNDCLASS/EX::cbWndExtra` field, in reality it needs to be large enough to hold at least `sizeof(LONG/_PTR)` number of bytes at the last byte offset you intend to specify in the `nIndex` parameter.

This is stated in the [`GetWindowLong()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga)/[`SetWindowLong()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) and [`GetWindowLongPtr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra)/[`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra) documentations:

> `nIndex`
>
> Type: int
>
> The zero-based offset to the value to be retrieved. **Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus four; for example, if you specified 12 or more bytes of extra memory, a value of 8 would be an index to the third 32-bit integer.**

> `nIndex`
>
> Type: int
>
> The zero-based offset to the value to be retrieved. **Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus the size of a `LONG_PTR`.**

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for both [Extra Class Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#extra-class-memory) and [Extra Window Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#extra-window-memory):

> *Because extra memory is allocated from the system's local heap, an application should use extra [class or window] memory sparingly. The RegisterClassEx function fails if the amount of extra [class or window] memory requested is greater than 40 bytes. If an application requires more than 40 bytes, it should allocate its own memory and store a pointer to the memory in the extra [class or window] memory.*